# Convert datatable to .xlsx format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

```
public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable dtExcel, string fileName)
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx";
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";  
    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = string.Empty;  
    string tab = "";
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dtExcel.Columns)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
        tab = "\t";
    }
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("\n");
    int i;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtExcel.Rows)
    {
        tab = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dtExcel.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
            tab = "\t";
        }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("\n");
    }

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();

}
```

Above code snippet generate only .xls format .If i change response time and File-name extension to .xlsx it does not work .Is there any other approach to do the same.

As per suggestion i have changed approach and generating .xlsx using openxml library.
But it throws error Unable to determine the identity of domain while generating large xlsx file.Please help

```
public static void ExportToexcel(DataTable dtExcel, string fileName)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        OpenXMLOffice openxmloffice = new OpenXMLOffice();
        MemoryStream msXML = openxmloffice.DataTableToMemoryStream(dtExcel);
        msXML.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        msXML.WriteTo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=DataTable.xlsx");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
    }
```

Comment: XLSX is an Open XML Spreadsheet format. You need a library that can generate those, such as [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Your code above isn't actually generating an Excel (.xls) file, but rather a tab-delimited text, which you are telling the client is an Excel file, and Excel handles the parsing when it opens the content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and most reliably method is to use a library like epplus, whcih even has methods like toDatatTable() and FromDataTable()

http://epplus.codeplex.com/